Breadcrumb without child components/routes
I was trying to follow the answer in Angular breadcrumbs with dynamic label to implement a breadcrumb navigation for my angular app.
The difference to my app is that my components don't have the child relationships of the example:
Snippet of my routing module:
{
    path: '',
    component: NavbarComponent,
    canActivate: [authGuard],
    children: [
      {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent},
      {path: 'teams', component: TeamsComponent, data: {breadcrumb: 'Teams'}},
      {path: 'teams/:teamId/members', component: TeamMembersComponent, data: {breadcrumb: 'Members'}},
      {path: 'projects', component: ProjectsComponent},
      {path: 'projects/:id', component: ProjectDetailsComponent},

I have a few cases where I have a list overview, then I click on an entry, e.g. a specific project or team and get to a detail view which is rendered in its own component.
Implementing the breadcrumb as stated I don't get the nested structure but only "Members" instead of "Teams / Members".
In the end I want to use static breadcrumbs, defined in the route config, dynamic breadcrumbs with resolvers.
How can I solve this? Is there a way to have those hierarchical routes without actually rendering the component in the parent? Currently I don't use router outlets or something similar.
Since I am kind of a beginner with angular I am not sure if my page structure is suboptimal or if I need to adjust the breadcrumb logic.
Update:
I worked around a bit and for the projects this works:
  {path: 'projects', data: {breadcrumb: "Projects"}, children: [
          {path: '', data: {breadcrumb: null}, component: ProjectsComponent},
          {path: ':id', data: { breadcrumb: null}, resolve: { apiData: projectResolver}, component: ProjectDetailsComponent},
        ]},

However, with a bit more complex routes I still have a problem with the breadcrumb I can not understand yet:
 {path: 'admin/products', data: { breadcrumb: "Products" }, children: [
          {path: '', data: {breadcrumb: null}, component: ProductCategoriesOverviewComponent},
          {
            path: ':id', data: {breadcrumb: null}, resolve: { apiData: productResolver }, children: [
              {path: '', data: {breadcrumb: null}, component: ProductsEditComponent },
              {path: 'asset', data: {breadcrumb: "Asset"}, component: AssetFeatureComponent},
            ]
          },
        ]
      },

When navigating to admin/products the breadcrumb shows Products /. However, one level deeper: admin/products/755a5cee-2e5b-45d0-bd0d-05595be15705 I get Products / ResolvedName /ResolvedName /. ResolvedName is duplicate. Whats strange it that it works when I go one step further /admin/products/755a5cee-2e5b-45d0-bd0d-05595be15705/asset : Products /ResolvedName /Asset /
The resolver is simple:
export const productResolver: ResolveFn<Observable<any>> = (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) => {
  const productService = inject(ProductService);
  const productId = route.paramMap.get('id');
  return productService.getProduct(productId!).pipe(
    map((product) => ({
      breadcrumb: product.name
    })))
};


if you use the nested routing using router-outlet that would be best in the long run, angular is more powerful when components have their own routes, with child routes, instead of a flat structure like this.

How can I use child components with router outlets when e.g. the detail component should not show anything of the parent component which gives e.g. the overview?

UPDATE:
You should keep a routing path, for each section you want to display as a breadcrumb.
{path: 'admin', data: { breadcrumb: "admin" }, children: [
 {path: 'products', data: { breadcrumb: "Products" }, children: [
          {path: '', data: {breadcrumb: null}, component: ProductCategoriesOverviewComponent},
          {
            path: ':id', data: {breadcrumb: null}, resolve: { apiData: productResolver }, children: [
              {path: '', data: {breadcrumb: null}, component: ProductsEditComponent },
              {path: 'asset', data: {breadcrumb: "Asset"}, component: AssetFeatureComponent},
            ]
          },
        ]
      },
   ],
}


You can try to keep a parent without a component and the child route will get rendered based on the path, you have to rework your routing to.
  {
    path: '',
    component: NavbarComponent,
    canActivate: [authGuard],
    children: [
      {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent},
      {
        path: 'teams', 
        data: {breadcrumb: 'Teams'}, 
        children: [
          { path: '', component: TeamsComponent },
          { path: '/:teamId/members', component: TeamMembersComponent, data: {breadcrumb: 'Members'} },
        ] 
      },
      {
        path: 'projects',
        children: [
          { path: '', component: ProjectsComponent },
          { path: '/:id', component: ProjectDetailsComponent },
        ] 
      },
      ...


Thanks! I took that approach and it works for my projects and probably teams too. However, for my product structure which is one level deeper I get some strange problems. I updated my initial post with the details. I would really appreciate it if you could take a look.

@Christian updated my answer, each path should have it's own router object if you want to display it on breadcrumbs.

Thanks a lot @Naren, that works well for me.
